# Node.js Canvas toBuffer method gets cached

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I have the following code to output two different pdf files. However I get the first result duplicated in the second file instead of two different results. What am I doing wrong?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {createCanvas} = require('canvas');

const canvasWidth = 768;
const canvasHeight = 1056;

const canvas = createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, 'pdf');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillText('Some text 1', 50, 50);
var buffer = canvas.toBuffer('application/pdf');
fs.writeFileSync(`../foo-1.pdf`, buffer );

ctx.fillText('More text 2', 150, 50);
var buffer2 = canvas.toBuffer('application/pdf');
fs.writeFileSync(`../foo-2.pdf`, buffer2 );
```

I tried to use asynchronous fs.fileWrite() method but it also leads to the same result.

Comment: That's odd, it's like the canvas becomes read-only after the first call to `toBuffer` (but I don't see anything the documentation that says that). Of course, you can always create a second canvas and write to that, but it's still odd.